# docker-compose: Installation of webserver volumes on winfsp drive (virtual drive)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-drive

I try to install paperless-ngx web server on a winfsp drive on Windows 11 (x64) via docker-compose:

1. `docker-compose pull`
2. `docker-compose run --rm webserver createsuperuser`
   => In step Building I get the following error message:

> Error response from daemon: There is no recognized file system on the
> data system.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this, whereas drive "X:" is a virtual winfsp drive:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  broker:
    image: docker.io/library/redis:7
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

  webserver:
    image: ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - gotenberg
      - tika
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-fs", "-S", "--max-time", "2", "http://localhost:8000"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - X:\paperless-ngx\data:/usr/src/paperless/data
      - X:\paperless-ngx\media:/usr/src/paperless/media
      - X:\paperless-ngx\export:/usr/src/paperless/export
      - X:\paperless-ngx\consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      PAPERLESS_REDIS: redis://broker:6379
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_ENABLED: 1
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_GOTENBERG_ENDPOINT: http://gotenberg:3000
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_ENDPOINT: http://tika:9998

  gotenberg:
    image: docker.io/gotenberg/gotenberg:7.8
    restart: unless-stopped

    # The gotenberg chromium route is used to convert .eml files. We do not
    # want to allow external content like tracking pixels or even javascript.
    command:
      - "gotenberg"
      - "--chromium-disable-javascript=true"
      - "--chromium-allow-list=file:///tmp/.*"

  tika:
    image: ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/tika:latest
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  data:
  media:
  redisdata:
```

If I choose a SSD drive on my computer everything works fine. Is there a way to get it to work with a virtual (winfsp) drive? If so, how?